# Understand Pointer and Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Can someone please explain how array is referenced by it's name, by prepending pointer and double pointer to its name like in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{  
    int a[3][2];
    a[0][0]=15;
    a[0][1]=150;
    a[1][0]=115;
    a[1][1]=165;
    a[2][0]=135;
    a[2][1]=139;
    printf( "%u\n", a);
    printf( "%u\n", *a);
    printf( "%u\n", **a);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your question better. I only see that the code is invalid (the first two `printf` statements).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

The first one

```
printf("%u\n",a);
```

prints the address of `a`, which is the same as the address of the first element.

The second one

```
printf("%u\n",*a);
```

dereferences `a` and gives the address of the first "row" of `a`

and the third one

```
printf("%u\n",**a);
```

dereferences the pointer to the first "row" of `a` and gives the value of the first element in this two dimensional array.

When you compile your example with warnings turned on, the compiler will already complain and so tell you about some of the types you use. When you give pointers as arguments to [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), you should use the format specifier `%p`

```
printf("%p\n",a);
printf("%p\n",*a);
```

Format specifier `%u` is for `unsigned int`, if you have `int`, it's better using specifier `%d`

```
printf("%d\n",**a);
```

Comment: Please mention that it's incorrect to use `%u` for cases 1 and 2.

Comment: `printf("%u\n",a/*a)` should be `printf("%p\n",a/*a)` in the first 2 cases. It should be `printf("%d\n",**a);` in the last case. Please consider updating the answer to add this.

Comment: And, for pedantry, the pointers ought to be cast to `void*`. On platforms where pointers to different types have different sizes, that is actually important (but those platforms may be hypothetical).

Comment: @DanielFischer `%p` is for pointer addresses, there's no distinction between "different" pointers. So, I'm curious if you have a link or some source for this claim.

Comment: 7.21.6.1, the specification of `fprintf` formats: "p  The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner."; and in paragraph 9 of 7.21.6.1: "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." Now, formalism aside, on platforms where pointers to all object types have the same size and representation, you can bet that the cast doesn't matter. But if sizes differ, the wrong number of bytes is read by `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

both `a` and `*a` is pointer so printing this in formatted output as in `printf()` use `%p` as format specifier.

Otherwise you will get warning messages by your compiler that

`warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[2]’
  warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’`

so try this:

```
printf("%p\n",a);
printf("%p\n",*a);
```

for third case `**a` is of type `int` so it's better to use `%d` or `%i`

```
printf("%d\n",**a);
```

According to C standard ,

```
ISO c99 standard : 7.19.6 Formatted input/output functions

9   If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

    If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion 

    specification, the behavior is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

it is  like if a is address than *a is value of a

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the first `printf` call, the expression `a` has type "3-element array of 2-element array of `int`"; by the rule above, the expression will be converted to type "pointer to 2-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[2]`) and its value is the same as `&a[0]`.

In the second `printf` call, the expression `*a` has type "2-element array of `int`"; by the rule above, the expression is to converted to type "pointer to `int`" (`int *`), and its value will be the same as `&a[0][0]` (which is the same as `&a[0]` - the address of the first element of an array is the same as the address of the array itself).

In the third `printf` call, the expression `**a` has type `int`, and its value is whatever is stored at `a[0][0]` (15 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

An examination of types is instructive.

`a` has type `int [3][2]`, i.e. an array of 3 arrays of 2 ints. However, array types cannot be assigned or passed in C. What is happening when you pass `a` to `printf` is that it *degrades* into a pointer to its first argument, i.e. `&a[0]`, which has type `int (*)[2]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 2 ints. That's the address that you see.

(Of course, the address of the first argument of an array is also the same as the address of the array itself, so if you did `printf("%u", &a);`, you would see the same address value (but the type would be different -- `&a` would have type `int (*)[3][2]`).)

Next, `*a`. You can only dereference a pointer, so `a` is first degraded into a pointer (`&a[0]`), and then dereferenced (`*&a[0]`). The result is `a[0]`, the first element of `a`. `a[0]` has type `int [2]`, i.e. array of 2 ints. Again as above, arrays cannot be passed, so when you pass it to `printf`, this is degraded into a pointer to its first argument i.e. `&a[0][0]`, which has type `int *`, pointer to int. That's the address that you see second. Again, it will be the same address as above since the address of `a[0]` is the same as the address of its first element, `a[0][0]` (but the type is different).

Finally, you have `**a`. As explained above, `*a` is `a`, degraded, then dereferenced. Remember above that `*a` has type `int [2]`, an array type. Like with `a`, when you dereference that, it implicitly degrades it into a pointer before dereferencing it. So `**a` is `a`, degraded, dereferenced, degraded, and dereferenced again. A more explicit description of what is happening is `*&(*&a[0])[0]`. The end result is `a[0][0]`, which has type `int`.